# How to determine what type of derived-class object to lazy-load from an associated object

Tags: c#, design

I'm modelling a system that is a combination of two distinct yet similar data repositories**: one containing patent data and one containing trademark data.  There is a very large overlap in the schemae, i.e. each database contains much of the same *type* of information.

To get more specific: there are "cases" -- patent cases and trademark cases -- the data for each being stored in the respective database.  A case has a lot of the same basic data regardless of whether it's a patent case or a trademark case, but, of course, there is also data that is unique to each type of case.  There are also "actions" associated with every case.  Unlike cases, though, actions share the exact same schema in both the patent and the trademark database.

In my application, I have a `Case` class with `PatentCase` and `TrademarkCase` that derive from it.  A `Case` has a collection of `Action` objects.  The `Action` also has a reference to its associated case.

I am employing lazy loading in both directions: `Case` with its associated `Action`s, and `Action` with its associated `Case`.  Now I know I *could* simply use dependency injection to give each `Action` a reference to its associated `Case`.  However, what I'm not showing here is that an `Action` could be used elsewhere and might be loaded before its associated case is loaded, thus the bi-directional lazy-loading.

Where I'm struggling is how to figure out what type of `Case` to lazy-load from the `Action` (see comment in `CaseLoader.GetCase`).  I don't want to have to store the type of action (or do I?) when the action is loaded from the respective repository, because then the action has a concern that it should not have, namely what repository it came from.  But I can't think of a better way to do it.

**What is the best way to determine what type of `Case` is associated with an `Action`?**

Here is the code:

```
public abstract class Case
{
    private ReadOnlyCollection<Action> _associatedActions;

    public ReadOnlyCollection<Action> AssociatedActions
    {
        get
        {
            if (_associatedActions == null) _associatedActions = ActionLoader.GetActions(this);
            return _associatedActions;
        }
    }
}

public class PatentCase : Case
{
    // patent stuff
}

public class TrademarkCase : Case
{
    // trademark stuff
}

public class Action
{
    private int _associatedCaseID;
    private Case _associatedCase;

    public Case AssociatedCase
    {
        get
        {
            if (_associatedCase == null) _associatedCase = CaseLoader.GetCase(this);
            return _associatedCase;
        }
    }
}

internal static class ActionLoader
{
    internal static ReadOnlyCollection<Action> GetActions(Case forCase)
    {
        if (forCase is PatentCase)
        {
            // retrieve actions from data layer, and return.
        }
        else if (forCase is TrademarkCase)
        {
            // retrieve actions from data layer, and return.
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The argument is not a derivation of case that this method knows about.");
        }
    }
}

internal static class CaseLoader
{
    internal static Case GetCase(Action forAssociatedAction)
    {
        // what is the best way to determine here what type of case is associated with the action?
    }
}
```

---

** The databases belong to a third-party vendor.  While, in another world, I could envision all of this existing in one database where all common data is better organized (thus making my task easier), the reality is they sell their products as separate packages -- we have purchased their "patent" and "trademark" packages -- hence the separate databases.  I'm simply trying to make a wrapper that effectively combines them.

Comment: Do the `Actions` have their own id?

Comment: Yes, they do.....

Comment: Ok, is the `Action` id unique across both the patent and trademark databases or just unique within on of them?  And, next, are you capturing the action id within the Action object?

Comment: Action ID is not guaranteed to be unique across both databases, only within their respective db, and yes I'm capturing the ID within the object.

Comment: Then Action is already tied to a particular database, and I would capture that as well, because you can't use the id without knowing which database.  Put another way, once you consider both databases, then an Action id key becomes the db primary key together with which db.  In other words, there is no value in the present design having Action pretending it doesn't know which db it came from.  (You could create a design that separates the db-specific part of Action from the rest of Action, but you should have a reason to do that, and as yet I don't see one.)

Comment: Right, but that was not my decision.  And since I know that actions always have the same form in both databases, I want to make one class to suit both.  Think [anti-corruption layer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?AnticorruptionLayer)

Comment: Right, so what I'm saying is that it is not appropriate to capture the id without also capturing which database it comes from because it would be error prone to try to do anything with the id without knowing which db it came from.  For example, you wouldn't even want to report the id to a user without also reporting what db it came from.

Comment: Okay, and then the single responsibility principle would dictate that I need to make two classes for each flavor of action...

Comment: I don't see why that would be required.  I am suggesting that you consider the Action id as an aggregated key once it is in the object.  I'd create a `struct ActionId { DBIdType dbId; ActionKeyType id; }` and put that in Action instead of just the key id as you have now, no?.  You can define Action as having the responsibility for an action and working across the two dbs.

Comment: So that's basically what I suggested, right?  " I don't want to have to store the type of action (or do I?) when the action is loaded from the respective repository".  My thought is that breaks separation of concerns.

Comment: It is ok to have a class that works with multiple databases.  It is not ok to capture an id that isn't unique in its (larger) context (here of multiple databases). You can make the action id unqiue by attaching the db id to it.  All that does is make a larger key that is now unique in the larger context.

Comment: Okay, well this has given me something to think about.  Thanks for your time and thoughtful comments.

Comment: On another note, consider using interfaces when you need to separate concerns.  Also, try to avoid statics in your essential design (i.e. things other than logging).  Static data is really bad, but static methods are bad too.  They make things harder to test and create tight coupling of dependencies.  Materialize an object for what the statics are doing, and you'll have a better design, easier to refactor and develop from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest having an `CaseReference` class which contains all the information required to find the case (target DB and case ID). You have two options with this approach:

```
class CaseReference {
    public CaseDatabase Database { get;set; } // enum which identifies the target database
    public int CaseId { get;set; }
}
```

Or you can use polymorphism:

```
abstract class CaseReference {
    public int CaseId { get;set; }
    // other methods which provide interface for logic to connect to database
}
class PatentCaseReference : CaseReference { ... }
class TrademarkCaseReference : CaseReference { ... }
```

Then your `Action` class needs to store a `CaseReference` instead of just the case ID. Your `CaseLoader` can either inspect the value of `CaseReference.Database` to determine which database to open in the first case, or defer to the logic in the `CaseReference` class in the second case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I think what your answer and the comments under my question seem to have in common is that there is no way I can get around having the `Action` (I know that's what you probably meant instead of `Case` when you said "Then your `Case` class needs to store a `CaseReference`") have knowledge of its source repository.

Comment: Yep, fixed the typo.